# login code with different user in php

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.x

table fields: username, password, acc_type

I am entering only username and password from form...

I want if I entered username and password in form then it validates username and password and acc_type in table.

**for ex** - if username = raj and password = 123 and acc_type = 1 then it redirects to index page.

**for ex** - if username = raj and password = 007 and acc_type = 2 then it redirects to registration page like wise..

If username and password is incorrect then it shows error...

Below is my code.

```
public function login() {  
        if (!empty($this->request->data)){         
            $this->User->set($this->request->data);

            if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('username','password')))){

                $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'User.username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                        'User.password' => md5($this->request->data['User']['password']),
                        'User.acc_type' => $this->request->data['User']['acc_type']                        
                    )
                )); 

                if((!empty($user)) && ($user.acc_type==1)){
                     $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
                }
                elseif((!empty($user)) && ($user.acc_type==2)){
                     $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->message('Invalid email / username or password');
                }
            }
        }    

    }
```

below function i used to add data in my user table..

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {   
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            //print_r($this->request->data) ;exit();
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

below is my model code

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule'    => array('email', true),
                'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.'
            ),
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A email is required'
            )
        )

    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {

            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = md5($this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**view code**

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create(array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'login','method'=>'POST')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <!-- <legend>
        <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
    </legend> -->
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?> 
 <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Register'), array('action' => 'add')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You say "help me to correct this"... What is the exact problem?

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean with _not working_? It gives an error? Give more details, please...

Comment: Ok, you won't find the user in yout table because you are searching also acc_type. I think you should remove 'User.acc_type' => $this->request->data['User']['acc_type']`from your query...

Comment: yes i want exactly...this..i also tried another code....i add this code in my question....but this also goes in else condition not in if....

Comment: i add one more login code in question..

Comment: why you not use auth login?

Comment: Instead of creating duplicates, you'd better try to figure out why the question was considered "not good" and work on that. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765260/login-with-multiple-user-and-validation-in-php**. This question lacks the same info as your original one, ie there is zero actual problem description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function login() {  
    if (!empty($this->request->data)){         
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

        if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('username','password')))){

            $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                    'User.password' => md5($this->request->data['User']['password']),
                    'User.acc_type' => $this->request->data['User']['acc_type']                        
                )
            )); 

            if((!empty($user)) && ($user['User']['acc_type']==1)){
                 $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
            }elseif((!empty($user)) && ($user['User']['acc_type']==2)){
                 $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->message('Invalid email / username or password');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sir..this shows only Invalid email / username or password ..but my username and password is correct...and also shows Undefined index: acc_type [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 106]

Comment: what type of encryption you have use at time of signup

Comment: Encrype your passwor according to signup

Comment: please share your code when you have save data in database

Comment: the prob is in this line...i am not getting this from textbox....  'User.acc_type' => $this->request->data['User']['acc_type'] .. i need to chk this in $user and then need to set condtion of acc_type in below line....

Comment: No, you check the `acc_type` in your _if_ clauses, but when you are finding the user, you must not add the `acc_type` condition as you don't get it from your form data.

Comment: Thanks tony...for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
                $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'User.username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                        'User.password' => md5($this->request->data['User']['password'])
                    )
                ));
```